# What would cause the css background-image property to not display an image while an HTML <img> will display it without issue?

Tags: html, css

I've got this image:

[image]

Which I'm trying to add to a webpage as a background image -- just for testing purposes.

I set up the simplest HTML file possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>
        My CSS Test Page
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And then linked it with this `css`:

```
body {
    background-image: url("trail.jpg");
}
```

And... It doesn't work.

I then tried it with single quotes, then no quotes.. still the same problem. Nothing shows up. I then thought maybe the image is somehow corrupt or something. So I added an img tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>
        My Css Test Page
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!!</h1>
<img src="trail.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Shows without any issues.

I then thought maybe a link issue. So I embedded the `css`.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>
        My Css Test Page
    </title>
    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url("trail.jpg");
    }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!!</h1>
<img src="trail.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

No luck.

So what am I missing?

Comment: browser used to test?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Chrome and Firefox. Latest versions. (edit: and now IE as well).

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GaKhA/

Comment: Remove the `img` for testing, and leave the `css` intact. Do you see any net request for the image? Does it return any 404?

Comment: Can you check `<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>
        My Css Test Page
    </title>
    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url("http://docs.gimp.org/en/images/filters/examples/color-taj-sample-colorize.jpg");
    }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to consider giving the path to the folder which has this image in your css-

`body {
background-image: url('../img/test.jpg');
}`

Comment: Oh... kill me... I thought since it was in the same directory as the html file I didn't need to do that.. Oy.. Thanks!

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro: If you put the image in the stylesheet, the image gets accessed relative to the folder that the stylesheet is in, because that's the file referencing the image. Likewise when you reference an image directly from the HTML page, the reference is relative to the folder that HTML file is in.